# Default gateway issue

Tags: active-directory, ip

Before I install AD in WServer 2003 - is it right to put a default gateway - ip of default gateway is the ip of another server.

Comment: Is the other server a router as well?

Comment: This is scary that you don't know the answer to this since you are  "actually setting up an AD of a larger organization".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default gateway should be set to the Router or Server that is handling your traffic (such as internet traffic).  If you are adding another server to an existing domain you would want to set the DNS IP to match the server which handles the name resolution to your domain (in which could be the local server or a different server if you are part of a larger organization other than a single AD server setup).

To clarify, you can set the server without a gateway address but this will not allow the server to access the internet for anything or any other resource based on the VLAN config.

For example if you have a network that is designed

```
2k3Server -> Router -> Internet
```

You would want to set the gateway IP as the Router IP

If you have a separate setup such as

```
2k3Server -> Firewall/Server -> Internet
```

The Firewall/Server would be the IP you would want to designate.

Comment: Im actually setting up an  AD of a larger organization. As far as i understand your answer, if i would want to create a server that has an internet access, i will set the gateway of another server as the router IP..

Comment: Without knowing your exact topology I would have a hard time giving you specifics but even if it is your default gateway would be based on the subnet that the server is on and gateway that would be defined for that subnet.

Comment: Im actually setting up an AD of a larger organization. As far as i understand your answer, if i would want to create a server that has an internet access, i will set the gateway of another server as the router IP.

Comment: Yes you would set the gateway as the gateway of your subnet which would be the Router IP of that subnet for it to have Internet Access.  In a sense if your network has a router gateway of 10.0.0.1 you would set your default gateway as 10.0.0.1 in a subnet of 255.0.0.0 or if you have a VLAN it would be based on the subnet of that VLAN gateway. http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Comment: "you can set the server without a gateway address" this may not be true for a network on vlans and multiple scopes where you require a gateway router to handle all of this.